# What is the offset for dpi and float values in setX, setY methods?[android]

Tags: android, dpi, pixel-density

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) inflate.inflate(R.layout.ani_image_view, null); 
    mAllImageViews.add(image);    
    image.setX(10);
    image.setY(100);
}
```

I try position a new `ImageView` at the coordinates 10,100. I also tried position the `ImageView` a 2000,100 but the `ImageView` keeps appearing at the same place either way.

I suspect it has to do with pixel density. What is the relation between float pixels and dpi values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever issues you have they are unrelated to `setX()` or `setY()` and pixel density. Anyway `setX()` and `setY()` expect an amount of pixels. If you look at the source code of `setX()` and `setY()` you see this:

```
/**
 * Sets the visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to setting the
 * {@link #setTranslationX(float) translationX} property to be the difference between
 * the x value passed in and the current {@link #getLeft() left} property.
 *
 * @param x The visual x position of this view, in pixels.
 */
public void setX(float x) {
    setTranslationX(x - mLeft);
}

/**
 * Sets the visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to setting the
 * {@link #setTranslationY(float) translationY} property to be the difference between
 * the y value passed in and the current {@link #getTop() top} property.
 *
 * @param y The visual y position of this view, in pixels.
 */
public void setY(float y) {
    setTranslationY(y - mTop);
}
```

In other words they basically just call `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()`. If your `View` is unaffected by calls to `setX()` and `setY()` I would first look for other causes. For example you may be trying to call `setX()` and `setY()` on the wrong `View` or another part of your code later on may overwrite your changes. I cannot give you a more detailed answer than that with the information you provided.